# ¿Por qué falla la siguiente URL que conecta un documento JS con un documento PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

La **estructura del proyecto** es la que sigue:

[image: duda01]

El documento *form.js* se encarga de recoger los datos pertinentes de la página web y enviarlos a *form.php*, el cual manipulará esos datos y mandará un correo a una persona concreta.

El caso es que la URL que debería conectar a *form.js* con *form.php* a través de ajax falla. Este es el código correspondiente:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../php/form.php",
            data: datos,
            success: function (res) {
                if (parseInt(res) == 1) {
                    $(".alert-enviar-3").css('display', 'block');
                } else {
                    $(".alert-enviar-2").css('display', 'block');
                }
            },
            error: function (res) {
                $(".alert-enviar-2").css('display', 'block');
            }
        });
```

La URL funciona bien si ponemos *form.php* en la misma carpeta que *form.js* y escribimos la URL "./form.php". Sin embargo, **la URL que podéis ver en el código falla**. ¿Por qué? Gracias.

Comment: Algun mensaje de error despedido por la consola?, te arroja algo?

Comment: Sí, me dice que no se encontró el archivo. El mensaje exacto lo podré poner en la pregunta esta tarde.

Comment: Las URL son relativas al documento HTML en el que se ejecuta el script, no a la URL desde la que se cargó el script en el documento HTML. No podemos decir cuáles son las URL reales involucradas y ni siquiera ha proporcionado una pista sobre la URL del documento HTML de origen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La URL debe ser relativa al lugar donde se ejecuta el código, en lugar de la ubicación del archivo javascript en sí. No puedo decir a partir de su captura de pantalla cómo es la estructura de su archivo, pero si lo está ejecutando en `index.php` en el directorio sobre PHP, sería de la siguiente manera:

```
url: "/form.php",
```

O si `index.php` está en la carpeta php

```
url: "form.php",
```

Answer (score 1):

La URL es siempre relativa a la raíz del proyecto.

Debería ser: `./php/form.php`

Quedando así:

```js
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./php/form.php",
            data: datos,
            success: function (res) {
                if (parseInt(res) == 1) {
                    $(".alert-enviar-3").css('display', 'block');
                } else {
                    $(".alert-enviar-2").css('display', 'block');
                }
            },
            error: function (res) {
                $(".alert-enviar-2").css('display', 'block');
            }
        });
```